# Updating timestamp column with new value - value of existing column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table lets say test having three columns objid, col1(Timestamp) and col2(Number). I want to update col1 with (new value - value of col2).

I can use below query for updating a single row -

```
update test set col1 = TO_TIMESTAMP('"+newDate+" 00.00.00.000000000','DD-MM-YYYY HH24: MI:SS:FF') - (select col2 from test where objid = 1) where objid = 1;
```

But i am facing problem while updating multiple rows by passing objid using IN.

```
update test set col1 = TO_TIMESTAMP('"+newDate+" 00.00.00.000000000','DD-MM-YYYY HH24: MI:SS:FF') - (select col2 from test where objid IN (1,2)) where objid IN (1,2);
```

I am not getting any clues to get it done.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both columns belong to the same table, you can write your query like this:

```
update test 
   set col1 = TO_TIMESTAMP('"+newDate+" 00.00.00.000000000','DD-MM-YYYY HH24: MI:SS:FF') - col2
 where objid IN (1,2);
```